# Queries re: Roku Web APIs & Push Notifications

Tags: web-services, api, subscription, roku

All,
As a newbie to Roku developer world, I have a bunch of queries re: Roku API.

The overall goal I am trying to achieve (by using these APIs) is as follows,

- Cancel a Roku Subscription by pinging some API with some parameters from our systems
- Refund money to Roku subscribers (either partially or completely) using some API
- Get notified by Roku when,

  - We get money from subscribers (at beginning of a new billing cycle)
  - Subscribers are refunded money (for whatever reason)
  - Subscribers have cancelled their subscription (from Roku directly)

I have been trying to go through their API docs & I am not able to see any consistent way of doing things. [This is the doc I am referring to](https://roku.app.box.com/s/fdyi280hrd4vhwjagbxo)

So I am wondering if their is a new/updated exhaustive version of their API.

Additionally if you can help me with following questions as well,

- What is the difference between "Issue Credit" & "Issue Refund"?
- What is the difference between the following Push notifications - "Sale", "Credit" & "Refund"?
- Is their a Java based client SDK for interacting with the Web APIs (& Push notifications)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get some answers from the Roku folks. Hope this helps someone else.

1. The link referred to earlier, is the current documentation on web services APIs & push notifications.
2. "Issue Credit" gives the users some credit to be used towards another roku product. "Issue Refund" gives users actual money.
3. "Sale" is for when user has bought some product & we as app-developer get money. "Credit" & "Refund" should be obvious from the previous point.
4. There is no Java based client SDK by Roku.